# Autocomplete not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to create a textbox that autocomplete when a user start do search for some name, but it's not working.
Here is my view:

```
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                    source: '@Url.Action("pesquisarUsuario")',
                    minLength: 0
                });
            });
    </script>






<h2>Index</h2>


@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("pesquisa", null, new { id = "txtPesq" })
    <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" />



}
```

And here is my controller:

```
 public JsonResult pesquisarUsuario(string term)
            {
                List<string> usuario;

                usuario = db.usuario.Where(u => u.nomecompleto.StartsWith(term))
                    .Select(u => u.nomecompleto).ToList();

                return Json(usuario, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Am I missing something? because my textbox does not show any users when I start do write.

Comment: you are doing `$("#txtSearch").autocomplete(` but your text box's id seems to be `txtPesq`

Comment: It was because i was trying different codes. I changed to txtPesq, and it still don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try if **usuario** returns anything. :-)

Try in your browser: `http://localhost:port/yourcontroller/pesquisarUsuario?term=t`

It should return all records starting with 't'.

If it does not return anything, here is your problem.

If it does, try to set the full url:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: 'http://yourserver/yourcontroller/pesquisarUsuario',
        minLength: 0
    });
});
```

**EDIT**:
I have created this tutorial with a fully working example: http://r2d2.cc/2014/09/11/autocomplete-jquery-ui-with-asp-net-mvc-simple-example/

Comment: usuario is working fine, I changed the source as you did, but it's not working. I followed this tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quQgUNteWxY) I don't know what I am missing...

Comment: Could you show how would you do a autocomplete? It's a simple one, I think... I just have to write someone's name and the textbox should show the users that have that name.

Comment: Sure. Give me a moment.